# Qt: Workaround for slow vertical scrolling in QGraphicsView with many items

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qgraphicsview

**EDIT** I found a surprisingly easy workaround, see end of the post. Nevertheless, I'm still open for comments and suggestion since my "fix" is clearly not how things are intended to work...

My Qt/PyQt Application has a QGraphicsView with a large Scene with many items stacked vertically. Verical Scrolling and other mouse interaction is very slow, but only for the exact upper half of the Scene, after scrolling to the second half, Mouse interaction suddenly becomes snappy. This behaviour makes me think there must be an issue with some BSTree holding the items, but I am not familiar with the Qt internals. I found an old Bug-Report ([QTBUG-11059](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11059)) for Qt 4.7, precisely describing my problem, but it was closed without any fix. I was able to reproduce this in Qt 5.4 & 5.5, confirming that this is a Qt-Problem, not a performance Problem of Python/PyQt.

I am unsure what the best fix/workaround for this issue would be:

- Is there some hidden optimisationflag/setting I missed that yields better performance? I tried setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex) but it was very slow. Also switching to QOpenGLWidget was not faster.
- I've read that painting to a QWidget is sometimes faster than QGraphicsView, but it would by a lot of extra work for the mouse handling I think. Are there other kinds of implementation possible?
- The Workaround proposed in the Bugreport was a scene horizontally stacked item, rotated 90°. This looks like a dirty but feasible option. But later on I want to implement more complex scenes with more mouse interaction and being forced to translate every coordinate would be a real pain to develop and to debug. Nevertheless it shows that the GraphicsView is generally capable of taking this complexity.
- is it possible to implement some kind of tiling, where items dynamically get attached and removed from the scene based on the visible area? Would this improve render speed? Is there any example code I can learn from?

I am thankful for any comments and suggestions on this bug.

Minimal code examples:

C++ Qt example, originally posted on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11059

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
QApplication app( argc, argv );

QGraphicsScene s;
QGraphicsScene s2;

for( int i=0;i<40000;i++ ) {
    QGraphicsRectItem *ri = new QGraphicsRectItem( 0, 0, 40, 20 );
    ri->setPos( 0, i*25 );
    s.addItem( ri );
    ri = new QGraphicsRectItem( 0, 0, 20, 40 );
    ri->setPos( i*25, 0 );
    s2.addItem( ri );
}
QGraphicsView v;
v.setWindowTitle( "BAD" );
v.setScene( &s );
v.show();
QGraphicsView v2;
v2.setWindowTitle( "GOOD" );
v2.rotate( 90 );
v2.setScene( &s2 );
v2.move( v.pos()+QPoint(v.width()+20,0) );
v2.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

My (slightly more complex) Python3/PyQt5 eample:

I am working on Linux64, Python 3.4.3 (Anaconda 2.3.0), Qt 5.5

```
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class  Track(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, pos=QPointF(),width=800,):
        super(Track, self).__init__()
        self.topleft = pos
        self.setPos(self.topleft)
        self.width= width
        self.height = 20
        self.pressed = False

        #caching boundingrect and shape improves speed
        self.br = QRectF(0,0,self.width+1,self.height+1)
        self.sh = QPainterPath()
        self.sh.addRect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.pressed = not self.pressed
            self.update()
            super(Track, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.br

    def shape(self):
        return self.sh

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black,0))
        if self.pressed:
            painter.setBrush(Qt.darkGreen)
        else:
            painter.setBrush(Qt.lightGray)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0,self.width,self.height)


class TrackView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TrackView, self).__init__()
        self.gs = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.gs)
        self.tracks = []
        for i in range(100000):
            rect = Track(QPointF(10,i*30))
            self.tracks.append(rect)
            self.gs.addItem(rect)
        self.gs.setSceneRect(0,0,1200,self.tracks[-1].topleft.y()+50)
        self.resize(1200,800)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = TrackView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT: I found a workaround**
Qt seems to have a problem with the GraphicsScene with height >> width (tall and narrow). The solution would be to set the sceneRect to width=height and disable the horizontal scroll bar. Ie. `self.gs.setSceneRect(0,0,1200,self.tracks[-1].topleft.y()+50)` becomes `self.gs.setSceneRect(0,0,3000050,3000050)`

Comment: Have you tried it in the context of the 40000 Chips example?  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html  This shows using a level of detail (lod) parameter to adjust the painting complexity.

Comment: Very interesting, indeed. Different LODs are on my list, but require more attention: Each track shows a part of a long sequence. On changing the zoom level, each track can hold a larger/smaller chunk so the entire view has to be populated again, just like a text editor reflows a long text whan changing its width.
But I really wonder why the Chip-Example is smooth, even when I divide the step size by 10 in the "Populate Scene" loop (100x more items)